# Remove Wi-Fi known network from command line / net shell (profile not saved)

Tags: windows, networking, shell, cmd.exe, netsh

Is it possible to remove a Wi-Fi known network (see below) from the command line / net shell in Windows? **Not a profile**

Known network from Windows 10: Settings -> Network & Internet -> WiFi -> Manage known networks.

I'm automatically connecting to many unique Wi-Fi networks as part of an end of line test for new products. The test uses the same profile just modified with the new SSID and passphrase, but the list of known networks keeps growing.

As it's using a single profile, the networks are not listed when executing `netsh wlan show profiles` so no option to delete them from the list.

Comment: You might have them as certificates in `certmgr.msc`. You might also [block them](https://www.howtogeek.com/331816/how-to-block-your-neighbors-wi-fi-network-from-appearing-on-windows/).

Comment: @harrymc Thanks. I had a look in the User Certificates Manager, but there's nothing relevant listed unfortunately. Also had a look in the Local Machine/Computer (certlm.msc).